# How can I get an email alert after a program is done executing?

Tags: email, windows-task-scheduler, events

How can I get an email after an application execution is completed in windows?

I have tried using Task Scheduler, however I am not able to figure out what event ID or how to configure email.

If not going wrong, log and source are selected as "application".

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be an event log entry made because the program completed unless the program specifically makes a log entry to announce it's done; which 99% of programs don't do (thankfully).

Instead, create a batch file or script (PowerShell is probably easiest) to launch the program, wait until it's done, and then email you.

Then run that batch/script instead of running the program directly (either manually or via a scheduled task).

Comment: I agree that scripting is easy to implement, in either PowerShell or CMD. However, an alternative worth investigating is **NirCmd** from NirSoft (http://nirsoft.net/), which has a huge number of options, including launching a command when another completes. There is an advantage is that **NirCmd** can run without a task-bar presence. There are a number of other very useful utilities on the site, and they are all freeware.

Comment: @AFH Seems reasonable, why not add that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that scripting is easy to implement, in either **PowerShell** or **CMD**.

However, an alternative worth investigating is **NirCmd** from [NirSoft](http://nirsoft.net), which has a huge number of options, including launching a command when another completes. There is an advantage is that **NirCmd** can run without a task-bar presence.

There are a number of other very useful utilities on the site, and they are all freeware.